# Clicking on an image upload button using JS or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I have the following code,

http://fiddle.jshell.net/hvLf8yua/

When I click on the image upload button using my mouse, it opens file dialog as expected. However, I couldn't trigger this using JQuery or JS. Could anyone tell me how I can achieve this? What I want is to open the file dialog box when such script is called.

Comment: you can't due to security, js can't interact through to the users computer.

Comment: that's not a valid answer. I don't want to fill in the dialog box, i want to simulate clicking on the area.

Comment: i know...and with a file input it won't work due to security, neither of thew answers below work, try them..it is a valid answer to your question, You can't. And a simple search would have told you that as it has been asked on here a thousand times already

Comment: So, what you say is that I can't even trigger click event on the file upload button. In my fiddle example, this button is in a div. I tried sending click event to div but it doesn't work as well? There must be a way to do it.

Comment: if you find one let me and the others on here who have asked the exact same question know.....

Comment: Well, I have a desktop application and there I move the mouse cursor to the exact location of the button and click on the mouse using windows events. That works ok but I wanted to do it with jquery.

Answer (score -2):

Here is an exmaple snippet you can refer to:-

```
<script>
function openFile()
{
  document.getElementById("dialog").click();
}
</script>
<body onload= "openFile()">
    <input type="file" id="dialog" style="display:none">
</body>
```

Comment: did you try that code in the jsfiddle that I gave in my main question? I know your example very well, but it doesn't work in the code that I gave.

Comment: Try this one but get it on your computer and run it. I've tried it and it works. Maybe there are some scripts on fiddle preventing it from working properly .http://fiddle.jshell.net/x3cct5bz/6/